# Number of Possible Tables

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorial-designs

A table of size $10$ x $5$ is defined with the following constraints.

1. A table entry must contain *exactly* one of these five alphabets $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.
2. Each alphabet must appear *exactly* once in each row.
3. Each alphabet must appear *exactly* twice in each column.

**Question:** What are the number of possible tables?

Following is an example of such a table:
$$a \quad b \quad c \quad d \quad e $$
$$a \quad b \quad c \quad e \quad d $$
$$b \quad c \quad d \quad a \quad e $$
$$b \quad c \quad d \quad e \quad a $$
$$c \quad d \quad e \quad a \quad b $$
$$c \quad d \quad e \quad b \quad a $$
$$d \quad e \quad a \quad c \quad b $$
$$d \quad e \quad a \quad b \quad c $$
$$e \quad a \quad b \quad d \quad c $$
$$e \quad a \quad b \quad c \quad d $$

I came across this subproblem while programming a question. Any ideas/hints are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want all the rows to be different, as in your example, or can we have duplicate rows?

Comment: @Steven We can have duplicate rows. :)

Comment: You ask for the number of tables, but a related problem may be generation of these tables. May be overkill, but an algorithm to solve that may be a backtracking search, as in Sudoku.

Comment: I believe that this makes the question a lot harder, at least from a mathematical point of view. Because if the rows were unique, then you could see your table as a combination of two distinct latin squares of order 5. With duplicate rows, the problem of double counting seems harder to work around.

Comment: @Steven If assuming distinct rows helps, I would be interested in it as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the extra restriction that all rows need to be distinct, I calculated the total number of tables to be $40182486220800 \approx 4\cdot10^{13}$.

For this I wrote a program which enumerates all tables in 'canonical form': the first row is $abcde$ and the rows are in lexicographic ordering (implying the first column is $aabbccddee$). This lead to $922768$ tables.
Now for each canonical table we can generate $5!\cdot9!$ distinct tables by first permuting the columns, and then permuting all non-first rows. On the other hand, the reversal of this process assigns exactly one canonical table to each table.
Therefore the total number of tables is $922768 \cdot 5! \cdot 9!$.

I made a similar calculation on the number of canonical tables, allowing equal rows. I adjusted the number of distinct permutations of the rows according to the amount of equal rows in the current table. If I made no mistakes, this gives $41376005798400 \approx 4.1\cdot10^{13}$ distinct tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven for making this much effort. Currently, I am going through your solution. I will get back to you in case of any doubt. :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{9!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}$ instead of just $9!$?

Comment: If all rows are distinct, every permutation of the rows leads to a different table. If rows can be equal, then you should multiply by $\frac{9!}{2^k}$, where $k$ is the number of pairs of equal rows (excluding the first, I think).

Comment: But the criteria of distinct rows is already covered in the subproblem, i.e., 922768 tables. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and it's precisely because they are different that every permutation leads to a unique table. So in that case you don't need to divide by $2^k$. Perhaps you could check with only 3 symbols to see how it works.